# How to pass Request Body from AngularJS with API

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json

I am trying to use json using API to retrieve data on a Google Map in AngularJS.

This is my code in Angular:

```
    $scope.loadData = function () {
    var map_info = {
            'ApiKey': '1iVuQy3FGK39d51',
            'ProjectId': '11'
        };
    var url = "http://localhost:63411/api/clientportal/?action=mapjson";
    return $http.post(url, map_info).then(function (response) {
        return response.data.MapData;
    });
};
```

But, when I run the code, it shown 'Cross-Origin Reuest Block' error.

[image]

Then, I search from the internet about this error, I come out with a solution to change $http.post to $http.jsonp.

```
  $scope.loadData = function () {
    var map_info = {
            'ApiKey': '1iVuQy3FGK39d51',
            'ProjectId': '11'
        };
    var url = "http://localhost:63411/api/clientportal/?action=mapjson";
    return $http.jsonp(url, map_info).then(function (response) {
        return response.data.MapData;
    });
};
```

It does go to the URL, however the Request Body is empty.
Since I created the API using C#, the 'Request.InputStream' is null.

```
string jsonPosted = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

So the 'jsonPosted' is null.

I did try on Postman, and it works. But not in Angular.

How do I send the Request Body properly?

I want the 'ApiKey' and 'ProjectId' to be included on Request Body.

Thank You.

Comment: What's the URL of your page?  That error usually means that the domain, subdomain or port of your application is different than the URL you're calling in your script.

Comment: @nixkuroi: the url is http://localhost:63411/api/clientportal/?action=mapjson

Comment: Not the url of the api.  What is the url of the page itself.  The one in the address bar?